# Determine if DataGridView Row being Dragged over Treeview

Tags: vb.net

How would I determine if the item I'm dragging from a DataGridView to a TreeView is actually a DataGridView Row?

I have TreeView that already has the ability to drag and drop into itself, however I want to put a check in the TreeView DragOver to check to see if its a TreeNode or a DataGridView Row.

I know I can check if its a TreeView Node by doing..

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", True) = False Then Exit Sub
```

But I tried doing..

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow", True) = False Then Exit Sub
```

But this isn't working for me.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown
        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left And DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then

            dragedItemText = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            dragedItemEXT = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            dragedItemRowIndex = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex

            DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(dragedItemText, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub


Public Sub TreeView1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs)
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow", True) Then
            Console.WriteLine("DataGridViewRow")
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'See if there is a TreeNode being dragged
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", True) Then
            'TreeNode found allow move effect
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
        Else
            'No TreeNode found, prevent move
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending it text, not the row.

Try this:

```
DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.CurrentRow, DragDropEffects.Copy)
```